# Is it possible to send extra data to DialogFlow agent without using context or event

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

Is it possible to send extra data from my server to DialogFlow. Like first request. Not form webhook. Without using `context` or `event`. 
 Because when I use `context` or `event` it is like me myself looking for what `intent` to use.

For example, DialogFlow has 3 `intents`. In the first and second DialogFlow use `user-name` in third no (`intent` has responses whom are without `user-name`). I send to DialogFlow only text end extra data (`user-name`) and DialogFlow will choose itself what `intent` to use and when to use extra data :

```
    queryInput: {
     text: {
      text: "How are you?",
      languageCode: "en",
     }
    },
    queryParams: {
     "parameters": { "user-name": "Johny" }
    }
```

Server send every request to DialogFlow with extra data (`user-name`). And DialogFlow respond with or without using `user-name` depends of `queryInput.text.text` and choosed `intent`

Comment: If you don't want use webhook then what are your options to communicate with your server?

Comment: Yes, I use webhook, but after.  At first my server send message with extra data to dialogflow, after dialogflow send respond to webhook. Maybe I don't understand it clearly.

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to send additional data when you're calling `detectIntent`? And you want this data to be passed along to the webhook from Dialogflow?